# How to get the index of a Container wrapped inside the inkWell

Tags: android, flutter, dart

> I have to implement on click on a `container` so I wrapped it inside
> `inkWell`. I need to get its index onTap() but not able to get it.

here is my code piece.

```
child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            _diagnosNetwork(context);
            
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 216,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 0, bottom: 0, right: 16, left: 16),
              itemCount: mealsListData.length,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final int count =
                    mealsListData.length > 10 ? 10 : mealsListData.length;
                final Animation<double> animation =
                    Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                        CurvedAnimation(
                            parent: animationController!,
                            curve: Interval((1 / count) * index, 1.0,
                                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));
                animationController?.forward();

                return MealsView(
                  mealsListData: mealsListData[index],
                  animation: animation,
                  animationController: animationController!,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: if you want an index then you have to create `InkWell` inside each list view item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the

> Listview.builder

when you return MealView you can wrap it under InkWell and return index in

> onTap()

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
return MealsView(
         mealsListData: mealsListData[index],
         animation: animation,
         animationController: animationController!,
       );
```

with

```
return InkWell(
         onTap: () {
          // you can use index here
         },
         child: MealsView(
            mealsListData: mealsListData[index],
            animation: animation,
            animationController: animationController!,
          );
       )
```